# Objective c. Push view down when user clicks "toggle keyboard" button on iPad keyboard

Tags: ipad, view, keyboard, hide, return

In my app, I have a textfield that when clicked brings up the keyboard. The view gets pushed up so that the keyboard doesn't block it. I have also implemented `textFieldShouldReturn:`, so that when the user clicks on return, the keyboard hides, and the view gets pushed back down.

The problem right now is that on the iPad keyboard, there is a button on the bottom right corner (i don't know what it is called). When clicked, it hides the keyboard. When clicked in my app, it hides the keyboard but does not return the view back to its original position. Is there some extra code I have to write for this button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but the other answer is not good. The problem here is that you're used to the iPhone UI, which usually uses the **Return** button to close the keyboard. This is not the case on the iPad.

On the iPad, when the user taps the "hide keyboard" button, the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is called, so you should register an observer for that notification.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideHandler:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                             object:nil];
  // ...
}

- (void) keyboardWillHideHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //code for pushing the view back down
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In your app add a button and sends it to back. Create an IBAction for that button when you click the app (back button) using Change the View frame to old (ie) set the view's y position to 0.

Comment: Hello, am not really getting your suggestion there. You want me to create a  button that when clicked brings the view back down? If so, I need a way to detect clicking of this "toggle keyboard" button, because the interface I have should not have any other buttons on it according to design :(